# Need to obtain value based on 2 criteria with or

Tags: google-sheets

I need a help to return a "Yes" or "No" based on different responses from the same company

the criteria is:

- if any employee responded "Sim" (="Yes") the result should be "Yes" for that company
- "no" if all responders filled as "Não"

In the Image:

- For BIO - should be YES
- For ALA      - should be NO

tried to use INDEX MATCH but couldnt

**Data**
[image: Data]

**EDIT:**
I'm having problems compiling answers according to each company
In column "I" i would like to have the result for each company.

**DataComp**
[image: DataComp]

Comment: There is no "Bemol" or "BIOMEDICAL" in your image. In general though, this sounds like it can be resolved with a simple ```IF``` statement.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(F2:F="";;IF(F2:F="Sim"; "Yes"; "No")))
```

---

### update:

try in i2 cell:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(H2:H; A:F; 6; 0)); 
 "Sim"; "Yes"); "Não"; "No"))
```

Comment: Could you help me further please?

Comment: @VictorYOO how?

Comment: What If i want to compile answers? using companys name as a parameter in another column?

Comment: @VictorYOO can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?

Comment: Added in original question, could not upload in comment. Thank you!

Comment: @VictorYOO answer updated